# Why does my df1.update(df2) give nonetype?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nonetype

I have 2 dataframes

df1

| Index | ID | m | n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | 10 | 11 |
| 1 | Z | nan | nan |

df2

| Index | ID | m | n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Z | 12 | 13 |

On doing df1.update(df2), it returns a Nonetype. What I want is:-

| Index | ID | m | n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | 10 | 11 |
| 1 | Z | 12 | 13 |

Can someone please help with this? The above is just an example, the actual dataset is much bigger hence would prefer an in-built function like .update() for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you're getting this error because the `update` function will update the dataframe in place will return `None`.

Another thing that you wanna do to for the correct update is to set the correct index first.

Here's one possible sol:

```
df1 = df1.set_index('ID')
df2 = df2.set_index('ID')
df1.update(df2)
print(df1)
```

##### OUTPUT:

```
    m   n
ID      
a   12.0    13.0
b   10.0    11.0
```